# Smart job board top menu items restriction for user

Tags: if-statement, frameworks, global

I'm currently working on Smart Job Board script customization. Here is my thing:

I want to restrict a menu item for guest and job seaker I'm writing the follow script but its not working.

```
{if $GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "JobSeeker"}    
    {if $GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "Guest"}
        <li><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/search-resumes/" >[[Search Resumes]]</a></li>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Can any tell me where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: I've used this app, for there's no such thing called guest, simply use a condition if user is logged in or not, if her is, than compare the group id

Comment: Thanks for your help `Mr.Alien` I've checked a user logged in or not by using `{if $GLOBALS.current_user.logged_in}`. The issue solved for me.

Comment: You welcome :)... but also you need to have a nested condition for job seeker

Comment: @Radhakrishna Rayidi Can you resell this script :)

Comment: @RainbowHat You mean the old script or customized script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to check weather user logged in or not. The following code helped me to hide a menu item in

> Smart-Job-Board

```
{if $GLOBALS.current_user.logged_in}
  {if $GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "JobSeeker"}    
    {if $GLOBALS.current_user.group.id != "Guest"}
        <li><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/search-resumes/" >[[Search Resumes]]</a></li>
    {/if}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

This helped me to hide a menu item.